# Send data (ArrayList) from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

I have only one `Activity` with only one associated `Fragment`. The `Fragment` is part of the `Navigation Drawer`. Now I have an `ArrayList<String>` which keeps changing. I want it such that, whenever I open the `Navigation Drawer`, the `ArrayList` should be passed to the `Fragment`.

The `Fragment` has a `ListView` which is populated with the `ArrayList`.

This is the `Activity` with the code for `Toolbar` and the `DrawerLayout`:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

OnlineNavDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (OnlineNavDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentUsers);
drawerFragment.setUp((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
```

This is the corresponding code of the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_nav_drawer, container, false);
    ListView lvOnline = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvOnlineUsers);
    return view;
}

public void setUp(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout,
            toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}
```

I am facing the following problem: how to pass `ArrayList<String>` from the `Activity` to the `Fragment`.

Also, I can't see at which point in the `Activity` code I can actually pass the data.

PS: Most of the code is modified version from one shown in a YouTube video series. And it works in its present form.

Comment: It depends on your code. You have to show at least the code of your activity.

Comment: @Foxinsocks Added code for both `Activity` and `Fragment`.

Comment: Instead of passing the data to the fragment when you open the drawer. Have the fragment use an interface to pull the data from the activity when it is needed. Usually in onResume().

Comment: I believe if the it will work better if a fragment is instatiated using getInstance() then pass values on it..

Comment: @Sheychan if he only sends the data in getInstance then it will not update every time he opens the drawer.

Comment: @doubleA Ohhhh then how about sharedpreferences??? it will be global

Comment: Honestly look at my answer. When the fragment resumes it will check the interface. If the interface is not null then it is associated with a callback in the main activity and can execute the code in the main activity that returns the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your fragment do this.

```
GetDataInterface sGetDataInterface;


public interface GetDataInterface {
    ArrayList<String> getDataList();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        sGetDataInterface= (GetDataInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + "must implement GetDataInterface Interface");
    }

    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(sGetDataInterface != null){
            mData = sGetDataInterface.getDataList();
    }
}
}
```

In your main activity

```
public class MainActivity implements YourFragmentName.GetDataInterface {
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> getDataList() {
        return mDataArrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use an EventBus ( like https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus ). Define your own event like `NavigationDataChangedEvent` and register your Fragment for `NavigationDataChangedEvent` in `Fragment.onViewCreated()` and **unregister** (important to avoid memory leaks) in `Fragment.onDestroyView()`. The Activity can simply post a `NavigationDataChangedEvent` whenever data has changed to inform the fragment. By using an EventBus your activity and fragment are decoupled ...